# stop save changes if multiple conditions not met excel vba

Tags: vba

I'm new in vba, i've been spending time and time surfing on internet trying to find solution but i could'nt
can someone assist on the below code, i want excel to force users to inter data in column K L and S whenever column B filled in with data (i.e column B is not empty) before save it.

may i know what i've missed below to make it run?!

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

Set rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B7:B10000")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each cell In rng
If Not IsEmpty(cell) And IsEmpty(cell.Offset(-1, 9)) Then
Application.Goto cell.Offset(-1, 9)
Cancel = True
MsgBox "Save is cancelled!" & _
vbNewLine & "" & vbNewLine & "Please fill in cells in column K."

End If
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Sub column_L()
Set rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B7:B10000")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each cell In rng
If Not IsEmpty(cell) And IsEmpty(cell.Offset(-1, 10)) Then
Application.Goto cell.Offset(-1, 10)
Cancel = True
MsgBox "Save is cancelled!" & vbNewLine & "" & vbNewLine & "Please fill in cells in column L."

End If
Next
Application.run macro:="column_L"
End Sub

Private Sub column_S()
Set rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B7:B10000")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each cell In rng
If Not IsEmpty(cell) And IsEmpty(cell.Offset(-1, 17)) Then
Application.Goto cell.Offset(-1, 17)
Cancel = True
MsgBox "Save is cancelled!" & _
vbNewLine & "" & vbNewLine & "Please fill in cells in column S."

End If
Next
Application.run macro:="column_S"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You had two subroutines (`column_L` and `column_S`) that weren't being called from anywhere but, if they had been, they would have gone into an infinite loop because they called themselves.

Your code should just be placed in the `BeforeSave` event as follows:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B7:B10000")
    Cancel = True
    For Each cell In rng
        If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
            'Check column K of current row
            If IsEmpty(cell.Offset(0, 9)) Then
                Application.Goto cell.Offset(0, 9)
                MsgBox "Save is cancelled!" & _
                       vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Please fill in cells in column K."
                Exit Sub
            End If
            'Check column L of current row
            If IsEmpty(cell.Offset(0, 10)) Then
                Application.Goto cell.Offset(0, 10)
                MsgBox "Save is cancelled!" & _
                       vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Please fill in cells in column L."
                Exit Sub
            End If
            'Check column S of current row
            If IsEmpty(cell.Offset(0, 17)) Then
                Application.Goto cell.Offset(0, 17)
                MsgBox "Save is cancelled!" & _
                       vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Please fill in cells in column S."
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Cancel = False
End Sub
```

(I removed your `ScreenUpdating` code, as your code doesn't actually update any cells, so I don't think you should see any flickering of the screen other than the movement caused by the `GoTo`, and you probably **want** the users to see that.)

Comment: appreciate, but it still doesn't  work...i.e i want users to be able to save only if column K, L or S are not empty.

Comment: @Florid Your original code seemed to be checking whether column K (and potentially L and S) was empty **on the row prior to a non-empty cell in column B**.  Is that what you wanted?  Or do you want to check the cell **on the same row** as the non-empty cell in column B?  Or does "be able to save only if column K, L or S are not empty" mean it is OK to save if any one of those columns is not empty (and it's only an error if all three columns are empty)?

Comment: all i need is whenever cell in column B is filled with data, then cell in the same row in columns K, L and S must also filled in with data otherwise file can't be saved.

Comment: @Florid - If you want to check the cell on the **same** row, rather than on the **previous** row, you need to change your offsets (e.g. from `.Offset(-1, 9)` to `.Offset(0, 9)`).  I have updated the answer.

Comment: can you help on another thing

Comment: can you help on another thing, now i need to have a unique Number/ID in cell column A whenever cell in column B is filled in with data after i click on save. e.g FTT-201702211230. ID is in text-date and time format.